# Is it possible to have a socket listening to two UDP IPs, one that is 127.0.0.1 (same machine) and a different computer at the same time?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, communication

An eye-tracking application I use utilizes UDP to send packets of data. I made a python socket on the same computer to listen and dump the data into a .txt file. I already have this much working.

A separate application also written in python (what the eye-tracked subject is seeing) is running on a separate computer. Because the eye-tracking application is continuous and sends unnecessary data, so far I've had to manually parse out the instances when the subject is looking at desired stimuli. I did this based on a manually synchronized start of both the stimuli and eye-tracking applications and then digging through the log file.

What I want to do is have the second computer act as a second UDP client, sending a packet of data to the socket on the eye-tracking computer everytime the subject is looking at stimuli (where a marker is inserted into the .txt file previously mentioned). Is it possible to have a socket listening to two IP addresses at one time?

Here's my socket script:

```
#GT Pocket client program

import datetime
import socket
now = datetime.datetime.now()
filename = 'C:\gazelog_' + now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M") + '.txt'

UDP_IP = '127.0.0.1' # The remote host (in this case our local computer)
UDP_PORT = 6666 # The same port as used by the GT server by default

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, #internet
                                socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #UDP 

sock.bind( (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT) )

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom( 1024) #I assume buffer size is 1024 bytes.
    print "Received Message:", data
    with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(str(data + "\n"))

sock.close()
myfile.close()
```

EDIT:

@abarnert I was able to bind to the host address on the Ethernet interface and send a message from computer B to computer A, but computer A was no long able to receive packets from itself. When I specified `UDP_IP = '0.0.0.0'` computer B was no longer able to send data across the Ethernet. When I specified `UDP_IP = ''` I received the `` `error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted ``

This have to do with the script I used on the Computer B to send the data:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "169.254.35.231" # this was the host address I was able to send through.
UDP_PORT = 6666
MESSAGE = "Start"

print ("UDP target IP:"), UDP_IP
print ("UDP target port:"), UDP_PORT
print ("message:"), MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT) )
```

I didn't know where (or if at all) I needed to specify INADDR_ANY, so I didn't. But I did try once where `import socket.INADDR_ANY` but got `ImportError: No module named INADDR_ANY`

Seems like a simple issue based on your response, so I'm not sure where I'm messing up.

EDIT2: I just reread your answer again and understand why socket.INADDR_ANY doesn't work. Please disregard that part of my previous edit

EDIT3: Okay so the reason that I wasn't picking up data when specifying the host IP was that the application I was collecting data from on Computer A was still specified to send to 127.0.0.1. So I figured it out. I am still curious why 0.0.0.0 didn't work though!

Comment: you can of course use two socket bound to different endpoints you want to listen on

Comment: From your edits, and the comments in your code, I think you're still mixing up the concept of remote and local addresses. The remote address is the address of the machine you want to talk to. This is the address you pass to `sendto` (or `connect`) in a client. This cannot be `0.0.0.0`. The local address is the address of your machine. Since your machine can have multiple addresses, you have to `bind` one of them, to listen on that address. This is where you want to use `0.0.0.0`, to mean "listen on all of my addresses".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A socket can only be bound to a single address at a time.*

If there happens to be a single address that handles both things you want, you can use a single socket to listen to it. In this case, the `INADDR_ANY` host (`0.0.0.0`) may be exactly what you're looking for—that will handle any (IPv4) connections on all interfaces, both loopback and otherwise. And even if there is no pre-existing address that does what you want, you may be able to set one up via, e.g., an ipfilter-type interface.

But otherwise, you have to create two sockets. Which means you need to either multiplex with something like `select`, or create two threads.

---

In your case, you want to specify a host that can listen to both the local machine, and another machine on the same Ethernet network. You *could* get your host address on the Ethernet interface and bind that. (Your machine can talk to itself on any of its interfaces.) Usually, getting your address on "whatever interface is the default" works for this too—you'll see code that binds to `socket.gethostname()` in some places, like the [Python Socket Programming HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html). But binding to `INADDR_ANY` is a lot simpler. Unless you want to make sure that machines on certain interfaces *can't* reach you (which is usually only a problem if you're, e.g., building a server intended to live on a firewall's DMZ), you'll usually want to use `INADDR_ANY`.

---

Finally, how do you bind to `INADDR_ANY`? The short answer is: just use `UDP_IP = ''`, or `UDP_IP = '0.0.0.0'` if you want to be more explicit. Anyone who understands sockets, even if they don't know any Python, will understand what `'0.0.0.0'` means in server code.(You may wonder why Python doesn't have a constant for this in the `socket` module, especially when even lower-level languages like C do. The answer is that it does, but it's not really usable.**)

---

* Note that being bound to a single address doesn't mean you can only receive packets from a single address; it means you can receive packets from all networks where that single address is reachable. For example, if your machine has a LAN connection, where your address is 10.0.0.100, and a WAN connection, where your address is 8.9.10.11, if you bind 10.0.0.100, you can receive packets from other LAN clients like 10.0.0.201 and 10.0.0.202. But you can't receive packets from WAN clients like 9.10.11.12 as 10.0.0.100.

** In the low-level sockets API, dotted-string addresses like `'0.0.0.0'` are converted to 32-bit integers like `0`. Python sometimes represents those integers as `int`s, and sometimes as 4-byte buffers like `b'\0\0\0\0'`. Depending on your platform and version, the `socket.INADDR_ANY` constant can be either `0` or `b'\0\0\0\0'`. The `bind` method will not take `0`, and may not take `b'\0\0\0\0'`. And you can't convert to `'0.0.0.0'` without first checking which form you have, then calling the right functions on it. This is ugly. That's why it's easier to just use `'0.0.0.0'`.

Comment: You might clarify that a single UDP socket can receive UDP packets from any number of sources.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: I don't think that's relevant to the OP's confusion here; I can't imagine anyone who could get this far without understanding the basics. But I could be wrong…

Comment: "What I want to do is have the second computer act as a second UDP client, sending a packet of data to the socket [...] Is it possible to have a socket listening to two IP addresses at one time?"  <-- that certainly sounds like 'confusion about the basics' to me ;)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Since the OP hasn't come back yet, it's hard to tell what he does and doesn't know. So it's probably safer to assume you may be right. I'll rewrite the answer as you suggested; thanks.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: It's surprisingly hard to explain this when you're not sure how much the listener already knows; can you read my edit and tell me if you think it works?

Comment: @abamert It looks good, except I modified your first paragraph (because INADDR_ANY is a special case that allows a socket to be effectively bound to all addresses of the local machine)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: That's what the entire second paragraph is about. At the sockets level, you're still bound to a single address—but at the inet level, that single address binds everything. I don't think it's a good idea to make the point loosely in the first sentence, and then contradict it with the more correct version in the next.

Comment: Well the basics of sockets are not that straight forward, it is easy to be confused A typical OS lets you bind() a TCP/UDP socket to either one interface("IP address") or all interfaces. But not anything inbetween, like 2 interfaces But e.g. an SCTP socket can be bound to any number of interfaces.

Comment: @abamert The way you have it, your second paragraph contradicts your first one.  (first paragraph:  "you can only bind a socket to a single address at a time" …… second paragraph:  "here's how to bind a socket to multiple addresses")

Comment: @abamert I am still relatively new to the basics, and I appreciate you two for trying to clear up my confusion! I think it might be helpful to first restate my intentions in case I butchered terminology making my OP confusing. I have two computers, Computer A and Computer B connected via Ethernet. Computer A is where I set up my UDP socket. I have it so that an application running on Computer A that sends data to the socket. I want Computer B to also be able to send data to the socket on Computer A. Am I over-complicating a simple problem? If I do `UDP_IP = 'INADDR_ANY'` will that solve it?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: No, 0.0.0.0 is a _single address_ that binds to _all interfaces_. If you're trying to merge the two into a single term to make it easier to understand, that's just going to cause more confusion.

Comment: @ejgennri: Yes, that will solve the problem. In this case, it sounds like you didn't even need it—if you just bind to computer A's ethernet address instead of its loopback address, computer A could still talk to itself while computer B also talked to it. However, it's usually simpler to just bind to INADDR_ANY than to try to find the address of one of your interfaces; almost all servers default to that.

Comment: @ejgennri: One more thing: `INADDR_ANY` isn't a string that you use as an address, it's a constant in the `socket` module. Let me edit the answer with more details.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks so much. I'm very pleased with your thorough answer!

Comment: @abarnert. I spoke to soon. Could you take a look at my edit above÷

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can bind a raw socket to an entire interface, but you appear to be using two different interfaces.

It's probably best to use two sockets with select().